A word to describe the feeling of work not being recognized
I’m looking for a way to describe this feeling. The situation is, a person puts in a lot of thought into for example writing about a subject. They give a well thought-out work, but maybe either their teacher or their audience thinks it’s not good. I want to talk about how they feel about it, but I don’t feel I could describe it to the point.
Because they put their own thought into the work, it contains some part of them. I thought of “discouraged,” or “doubts their self-worth,” “feel they’re nothing.” But it doesn’t have the meaning that the product of they created is considered poor. In my language there’s a phrase that’s like “write off (or dismiss?) their whole being.” I know it doesn’t sound right in English, does it? How would you say it?
Thank you.

You could say "unappreciated" or "under-appreciated" or that you are "being written off", and the last means not regarded as capable of making a valuable contribution or not regarded as being "up to" (i.e. suited to or suitable for) a task or job.

As happens often, maybe the best way is not a single idiomatic phrase but direct language. "I put my heart and soul into that project, and when you dismiss it I feel like you dismiss me."

@TimR Yes under-appreciated but still a bit different. I think I also used the word "dismiss" wrong. I don't want to say "this person isn't qualified for a job" like they dismiss what you can do. It's not about ability. I feel like this person makes a product and it's not approved. For example an artist that people don't see the point of their work and think it's really bad. Thank you for the suggestions.

@AndyBonner "Heart and soul" helps me get out what I want to say more. Thanks!

Lol, I guess I did use an idiom after all...

If I interpret correctly - OP wants to convey someone didn't get the anticipated result after putting in a lot of hard work. I have framed some sentences:

My efforts did not provide the anticipated results.
I didn't get the fruits of my labour.
I did not reap the benefits of my efforts.
I did not reap the rewards of my effort
My hard work did not pay off.
My efforts did not get the desired results.
My efforts did not yield the expected outcomes.

**Words/ Phrases:
Feeling undervalued,
demotivate
(unappreciated, unrecognised) = efforts are not being recognised or appreciated.
not given credit where it is due.
achievements are not rewarded.
Unproductive work,
disillusioned,
lack self-efficacy,
underperform,
